# Elasticsearch: how to find a document by number in logs

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an error in kibana
"The length [2658823] of field [message] in doc[235892]/index[mylog-2023.02.10] exceeds the [index.highlight.max_analyzed_offset] limit [1000000]. To avoid this error, set the query parameter [max_analyzed_offset] to a value less than index setting [1000000] and this will tolerate long field values by truncating them."

I know how to deal with it (change "index.highlight.max_analyzed_offset" for an index, or set the query parameter), but I want to find the document with long field and examine it.

If i try to find it by id, i get this:

q:

> GET mylog-2023.02.10/_search
> {
> "query": {
> "terms": {
> "_id": [ "235892" ]
> }
> }
> }

a:

> {
> "took" : 1,
> "timed_out" : false,
> "_shards" : {
> "total" : 1,
> "successful" : 1,
> "skipped" : 0,
> "failed" : 0
> },
> "hits" : {
> "total" : {
> "value" : 0,
> "relation" : "eq"
> },
> "max_score" : null,
> "hits" : [ ]
> }
> }

q:

> GET mylog-2023.02.10/_doc/235892

a:

> {   "_index" : "mylog-2023.02.10",   "_type" : "_doc",   "_id" :
> "235892",   "found" : false }

Maybe this number (doc[235892]) is not id? How can i find this document?

Answer (score 0):

try use Query IDs:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "ids" : {
      "values" : ["1", "4", "100"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: same:

`GET mylog-2023.02.10/_search
{
  "query": {
    "ids" : {
      "values" : ["235892"]
    }
  }
}`

a:
`{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}`