# Find Elasticsearch document that is giving me an error, based on ES internal identifier

Tags: elasticsearch

When I do a search query in Elasticsearch (This is from a Rails app which is connecting to a Rails-based API which is in turn based on an Elasticsearch index, the query is basically doing a text search on all documents in the API), it is giving me the following error:
`The length [3618270] of field [text] in doc[126737]/index[my-index] exceeds the [index.highlight.max_analyzed_offset] limit [1000000]. To avoid this error, set the query parameter [max_analyzed_offset] to a value less than index setting [1000000] and this will tolerate long field values by truncating them.`
This appears to indicate that the `text` field for a particular entry is too long. It would be helpful to be able to locate the particular document and perhaps truncate that field when it is ingested into the API. However, it is not obvious to be how to find it given `doc[126737]` which appears to be an identifier internal to Elasticsearch.

I have a local instance of Elasticsearch running and did a query with
`http://localhost:9200/my-index/_doc/126737`, thinking this might be a way to retrieve the document based on the internal id. Instead I got the following indicating it is not found:

```
{
  "_index": "my-index",
  "_id": "126737",
  "found": false
}
```

All of the documents do have an id field that is being populated, but with something we are generating manually for our project. I think, correct me if I am wrong, that elasticsearch is looking for that manually generated id and not finding it. Is there any way to look up the document directly based on the id in the error message?

Comment: After posting this SO pointed me in "related questions" to this question which is basically the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75408570/elasticsearch-how-to-find-a-document-by-number-in-logs?rq=2. I was unable to flag my own question as a duplicate because there are no accepted answers.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, that ID is useless as it's internal to ES.

It's a [pre-defined limit](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/highlighting.html#offsets-strategy) to protect against running out of memory when highlighting big text fields. If you're ok with taking the risk, you can decide to augment that limit to something bigger than 3618270 by changing the index setting with this command

```
PUT whitman-new/_settings
{
    "index.highlight.max_analyzed_offset": 4000000
}
```

Comment: I would still like to identify the document that is causing the problem.

Comment: If you're using an older version of ES you can try to match `_uid` instead of `_id` but not sure it's gonna work either. Does your `text` field have a keyword sub-field by any chance? Would not make sense given it's free text, but asking anyway as that can help find the document in question